# Does belly fat hangs before getting less?

Tags: strength-training, body-fat, bellyfat

It's been 2 weeks of me working out in strength and transformation change. I don't see any much difference expect my body fat is 4 percent less. And weight has reduced. But pictures don't lie. So I took with a 35 days difference. And I see is my tummy hanging out. 
[image: left one 35 days old and right one is latest (after 35 days)]
My question is, 
1.does the fat hangs like in my picture prior to getting burned away and going away?
2.If I see body fat and weight changes, why doesn't if show in picture?

Answer (score 1):

For men, the stomach is often the last place that fat is lost. It changes from person to person, but you'll lose fat in a particular order, pretty much the opposite of the order in which you put it on. Most men put on belly fat first and lose it last. If you've lost fat, look at other places first: your arms, back, thighs, chest, face, etc.

Comment: I don't see any changes. Can you see it between two images? The question remains, why is my belly seems like hanging out on right pic?

Comment: The problem here is your expectations are set way too high for such a small time frame. Bottom line.

Answer (score 1):

1. When fat is burned, it just goes away. What could be hanging out is excessive skin that is left if you lose fat very fast and/or have skin elasticity issues, but it's not your case. The effect of "hanging out" on 2nd picture could be explained by different level of tension in you ABS, the position that you would feel as "relaxed" is nonetheless different depending on how did you exercise lately, what time of day it is, how much did you eat etc.
2. As it was said in previous answer, belly is usually the last thing to go away. How much did your weight reduce? You should probably just give it some more time.